# ImportError: cannot import name 'get_rule_detail' from 'jira_plug.utils.rule' (D:\code\ido-jira-plug\IdoJiraPlug\jira_plug\utils\rule.py)

Tags: python, django, python-import, python-importlib, import-module

My Django project have a problem when it starts

```
2022-09-01 09:22:51,525 [MainThread:25612] [django.utils.autoreload:612] [INFO]- Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python37\lib\threading.py", line 926, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Python37\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 118, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 396, in check
    databases=databases,
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 70, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 408, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 589, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 582, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "D:\code\ido-jira-plug\IdoJiraPlug\IdoJiraPlug\urls.py", line 23, in <module>
    path('jira/', include('jira_plug.urls', namespace='jira_plug')),
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\urls\conf.py", line 34, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "D:\code\ido-jira-plug\IdoJiraPlug\jira_plug\urls.py", line 5, in <module>
    from . import api
  File "D:\code\ido-jira-plug\IdoJiraPlug\jira_plug\api\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .config import *
  File "D:\code\ido-jira-plug\IdoJiraPlug\jira_plug\api\config.py", line 5, in <module>
    from jira_plug.utils import JiraAction
  File "D:\code\ido-jira-plug\IdoJiraPlug\jira_plug\utils\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .rule import *
  File "D:\code\ido-jira-plug\IdoJiraPlug\jira_plug\utils\rule.py", line 4, in <module>
    from jira_plug.serializers import RuleConfigInfoSerializer
  File "D:\code\ido-jira-plug\IdoJiraPlug\jira_plug\serializers\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .request_serializer import *
  File "D:\code\ido-jira-plug\IdoJiraPlug\jira_plug\serializers\request_serializer.py", line 6, in <module>
    from jira_plug.utils import JiraAction, get_msg_data, get_rule_detail, handle_message_content
ImportError: cannot import name 'get_rule_detail' from 'jira_plug.utils' (D:\code\ido-jira-plug\IdoJiraPlug\jira_plug\utils\__init__.py)
```

This is my project,

```
IdoJiraPlug
    - jira_plug
        - __init__.py
        - api
            __init__.py
            config.py
        - serializers
            __init__.py
            request_serializer.py
        - utils
            __init__.py
            rule.py
        - urls.py
    - manage.py
```

jira_plug.utils.__init__.py

```
from .rule import *
```

jira_plug.utils.rule.py

```
...
from jira_plug.serializers import RuleConfigInfoSerializer
...
```

jira_plug.serializers.__init__.py

```
from .request_serializer import *
```

jira_plug.serializers.request_serializer.py

```
...
from jira_plug.utils import JiraAction, get_msg_data, get_rule_detail, handle_message_content
...
```

I feel like this is because rule.py and request_serializer.py import each other,but I don't known real reason.
I try to use 'from jira_plug.utils.rule import get_rule_detail, handle_message_content', but it still has this error.

Answer (score 0):

in your `jira_plug` app in `utils.py` file you are don't have `get_rule_detail` class or function or name of variable.

If you are sure, that it is exists - try to check every letter in name in utils.py, probably you find the error.

Comment: Thank you,I have to solve this problem.That is because circular import.

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem.The real reason is **circular import**.When django starts,**urls.py** will be used by **import_module()**.python will begin to load module step by step according to jira_plug.urls.py.

1. jira_plug.urls.py, 5 line: `from . import api`,then python will to load **jira_plug.api.__init__.py** module.
2. jira_plug.api.__init__.py, 3 line: `from .config import *`,then python will to load **jira_plug.api.config.py** module.
3. jira_plug.api.config.py, 5 line: `from jira_plug.utils import JiraAction`,then python will to load **jira_plug.utils.__init__.py** module.
4. jira_plug.utils.__init__.py, 6 line: `from .rule import *`,then python will to load **jira_plug.utils.rule.py** module.
5. jira_plug.utils.rule.py, 4 line: `from jira_plug.serializers import RuleConfigInfoSerializer`,then python will to load **jira_plug.serializers.__init__.py** module.
6. jira_plug.serializers.__init__.py, 4 line: `from .request_serializer import *`,then python will to load **jira_plug.serializers.request_serializer.py** module.
7. jira_plug.serializers.request_serializer.py, 6 line: `from jira_plug.utils import JiraAction, get_msg_data, get_rule_detail, handle_message_content`, then python will to load **jira_plug.utils** package.

**Step 5 , Step 6 and Step 7 lead to this error.**
A --> B --> A, module A have not be loaded, B module also load A module,so python interpreter caused "ImportError".

The best solution is planning to abstract **common package**.

Temporary solution is modify **jira_plug.api.config.py**.

```
# from jira_plug.utils import JiraAction
from jira_plug.utils.call_jira import JiraAction
```

This will lead to disappear after step 3. But this is a **hidden danger**, I already have to abstract common methods. **This solution is just an example!**